# BBox and KVP for WFS

Tags: wfs

I have this WFS: https://inspire-wfs.maanmittauslaitos.fi/inspire-wfs/au?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities with different SRS available. I would like to run a URL request to select in a Bounding Box to try this function with GetFeature request.

I did this: https://inspire-wfs.maanmittauslaitos.fi/inspire-wfs/au?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&COUNT=5&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeUnit&SRSNAME=EPSG:4258&BBOX=59.6522,22.211,62.619,28.2755,EPSG:4258 with the definition of the SRS in the KVP and in the BBox parameter.

But it does not work: I can´t get any feature type back!

Is there a problem in the URL I did?

Comment: WFS 2.0.0 should use BBOX in order of axes specified by the referenced CRS.  EPSG:4258 is lat long, so BBOX should be min lat, min long, max lat, max long.  If the server is expecting long lat, the server is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounding box is wrong - you mixed lat lon. This one works:

https://inspire-wfs.maanmittauslaitos.fi/inspire-wfs/au?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&COUNT=5&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeUnit&SRSNAME=EPSG:4258&BBOX=22.211,59.6522,28.2755,62.619,EPSG:4258

Comment: But if you want to use Lat-Lon axis order use long format for the srsname: `https://inspire-wfs.maanmittauslaitos.fi/inspire-wfs/au?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&COUNT=5&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeUnit&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&BBOX=59.6522,22.211,62.619,28.2755,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258`

Comment: so addind ´urn:ogc:def:crs:´ for the SRS is changing the long/lat order to lat/long?